# var_dump shows string(185) ""

Tags: php, string

A string in my code consists of content pulled from a txt file via a REST API. var_dump of the string shows - string(185) "". Why is the string empty when it's length is 185? What is causing this? Encoding issues?

Additional information (edit):
It's not html. It's .txt version of a .doc file. If I view it in the browser I can see the text. But, if I put it in a string and try to echo it, it's empty.

Comment: view source on the page and be enlightened

Comment: Probably the byte order mark taking up space, or you've got some screwy character inside your database (if used in a DB); I've seen that happen before.

Comment: How are you accessing the file? Show us your code, including content of the .txt file.

Comment: Do `var_dump(bin2hex($str));` so we can see what the problematic bytes are.

Comment: Or just never come back. That works too.

Comment: I just had a similar problem, though not as extreme: I dumped a string that was written as two lines (and few tabs were used) and var_dump shown some fifteen extra chars in the length count which were not shown as part of the bumped string. So I guess most or all of your 185 chars are new lines, tabs and non-printable characters. Showing '' only as the string, there might be some other error too, removing the printable ones.

Answer (score 5):

Is the string HTML? Are you viewing it in a browser? HTML tags will not show up in the browser, they'll show up in View Source.

Alternatively, if it's 185 non-printable characters, they won't show up either.

So try [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) on it.

Comment: It's not html. It's .txt version of a .doc file. If I view it in the browser I can see the text. But, if I put it in a string and try to echo it, it's empty. var_dump shows that the length is 185 (which is correct), but an empty string.

Comment: @om_deshpande 185 is not very big. What content exactly is inside your .txt file?

Comment: Text from a .doc file has been parsed and put into this .txt file.

Comment: @om_deshpande .doc from which software?

Comment: I can't be 100% sure, I haven't built the parser. But, I can confidently assume that the .doc file is user generated, so it's from MS Word (some older version of Office)

Comment: @om_deshpande Hard to tell without seeing your parser, code, and the document in question.

Comment: hmm. I'm tempted to show you the document. It's confidential, so can't do that :)

Comment: @om_deshpande Ah ok, I understand. Well, chances are that Word is adding something to it. Hard to say. However is your parser and code confidential as well? The one you use to access it and execute?

Comment: Yup. I guess I'll have a look at the original doc and the parser. I'll let you guys know.

Comment: @om_deshpande Ok. And to address me directly, add the `@` symbol followed by my name. Good luck.